# How verify a string having only numbers and a decimal(dot) using swift

Tags: swift, string, decimal, number-formatting

I have a text box where if I enter a number it should convert that number into a decimal number for example if

- I enter 56 then click on validate button it will converted and show 56.0
- I enter 56.0 then click on validate button it will converted and show 56.0

So here I need to verify like converted value 56.0 is now a decimal number may be by checking `string.contains(".")` if yes
then split it by "." using code below

```
let enteredValue = "56.0"
enteredValue.components(separatedBy: " ")
        let expectedEnteredValueLastPart = array.last!
enteredValue.components(separatedBy: " ")
        let expectedEnteredValueFirstPart = array.first!
```

Now I have the first part "56" and second part "0" using regex how to verify both the parts contains only number.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILBi5.png)

Comment: no need to use regex you can simply use `expectedEnteredValueFirstPart.allSatisfy({"0"..."9" ~= $0})`

Comment: I would generally recommend to stop using regular expressions and just try to parse that number using a `NumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
 extension String {
    var isNumeric: Bool {
        guard self.count > 0 else { return false }
        let nums: Set<Character> = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
        return Set(self).isSubset(of: nums)
    }
}

var enteredValue = "56.0"

var firstPart = enteredValue.components(separatedBy: ".").first!
var secondPart = enteredValue.components(separatedBy: ".").last!

if firstPart.isNumeric && secondPart.isNumeric {
    //do something
}
```

I would recommend using `UITextFieldDelegate` or `UITextViewDelegate` for restricting characters.